# How can I have something similar to the @deprecated annotation?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I have a TypeScript Next.js app, and I use VSC when I'm coding.

I like this feature: if I add a JSDoc annotation of `@deprecated` above a function, then all usages of that function have the function name struck through as a visual warning:

[image: screenshot]

Often, I feel tempted to mark functions as `@deprecated` just to ensure that whenever someone attempts to use them, they pay extra close attention and read the comments.

But I don't want to use the word "deprecated" when I have no plans to kill that function.

For example, sometimes I just want to grab attention to say: *"Instead of calling this function, you almost definitely should be calling [this other function]."*

Is there some other annotation available? If not, how could I create one?

I want all usages to automatically change the appearance of the function name (either with strike-through or some other style).

Comment: That's what deprecated already means - you don't necessarily have any plans to _ever_ completely remove it, but something else should be used instead. [_"....the discouragement of use of some terminology, feature, design, or practice, typically because it has been superseded or is no longer considered efficient or safe, without completely removing it or prohibiting its use."_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation)

Comment: @jonrsharpe but keyword "_almost_ definitely".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be such a feature, but I'm not aware of it, and I am more confident that there isn't such a feature. Deprecation is mostly a kind of a "hard-coded" status type. See for yourself in [the extension API docs for VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api). Same goes for the deprecation [modifier in semantic highlighting](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide#standard-token-types-and-modifiers).

But on the topic of syntax highlighting, both semantic and TextMate-based syntax highlighting in VS Code support strikethrough, italics, bold, and underlining in `fontStyle` modifications. So you could write a VS Code extension that either contributes a TextMate or semantic highlighting scope for your function and then define the font styling for it. Sounds a little overboard, but it should be possible.